# Windows process state / thread state...?

Tags: operating-system

http://www.macdesign.net/academic/it4813/it4813-Submitted/IT4813-u03a1-Process_States.html

This URL is Windows thread state. (At the bottom)

Can I thought the same as the state of the process of the window?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Thread lifecycle in .NET framework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8966636/thread-lifecycle-in-net-framework)

Comment: Typically one of the process's threads acts as the main UI thread which creates the application windows and dispatches the message queue. This is typical scenario but a Windows process can create windows and handle their messages on as many threads it wants. When in doubt, use as normative reference source the [official MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681917(v=vs.85).aspx). The article you're quoting from is 10 years old